# Iterating through a list where I have to grab data from the first item for use in the last item

Tags: python, dna-sequence

This is a follow-up to a previous question I had asked:  [Processing a sub-list of variable size within a larger list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063387/processing-a-sub-list-of-variable-size-within-a-larger-list).

I managed to use itertools to get groups of DNA fragments out, but now I'm faced with a different problem.

I need to design primers based on these groups of DNA fragments. Primers are designed by including overlaps from different DNA fragments. Let's say I have three DNA fragments in a list, fragments A, B, and C. I need to extract:

- the last 20 nucleotides (n.t.) of C to concatenate (in order) with the first 40 n.t. of A,
- the reverse complement (RC) of the first 20 n.t. of B to concatenate in order with the RC of the last n.t. of A,
- the last 20 n.t. of A to concatenate with the first 40 n.t. of B,
- the RC of the first 20 n.t. of C to concatenate with the RC of the last 40 n.t. of B,
- the last 20 n.t. of C to concatenate with the first 40 n.t. of A,
- the RC of the first 20 n.t. of A to concatenate with the RC of the last 40 n.t. of C.

I can't seem to solve this problem, and I'm not sure where's the best place for me to start on this...

Code that I've already written so far outputs just "group 1" (on purpose, so I can minimize the amount of visual output I'm dealing with). Here it is:

```
#import BioPython Tools
from Bio.Seq import Seq
from Bio.Alphabet import IUPAC

#import csv tools
import csv
import sys
import os
import itertools

with open('constructs-to-make.csv', 'rU') as constructs:
    construct_list = csv.DictReader(constructs)
    def get_construct_number(row):
        return row["Construct"]
    def get_strategy(row):
        return row["Strategy"]
##    construct_list.next()
##    construct_number = 1
    primer_list = []
##    temp_list = []
##    counter = 2
    groups = []

##    for row in construct_list:
##        print(row)
##
    for key, items in itertools.groupby(construct_list, key=get_construct_number):
        for subitems in items:
            #here, I am trying to get the annealing portion of the Gibson sequence out
            if subitems['Strategy'] == 'Gibson' and subitems['Construct'] == '1':
                print(subitems['Construct'])
                fw_anneal = Seq(subitems['Sequence'][0:40], IUPAC.unambiguous_dna)
                print(fw_anneal)
                re_anneal = Seq(subitems['Sequence'][-40:], IUPAC.unambiguous_dna).reverse_complement()
                print(re_anneal)
                fw_overhang = Seq(subitems['Sequence'][0:20], IUPAC.unambiguous_dna).reverse_complement()
                print(fw_overhang)
                re_overhang = Seq(subitems['Sequence'][-20:], IUPAC.unambiguous_dna)
                print(re_overhang)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: One approach would be to first design a little domain-specific language that could be used to express the combinations in each of the 6 extractions in a formulaic way. Next implement an interpreter to parse, evaluate, and compute the result of such an expression given three DNA fragments designated as A, B, & C. Once that is working you should then be able to apply such expression any combination of fragments -- such as those you generating. There are many tools avaiable to help you evaluate [little languages](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LittleLanguage), an idea that's been around a long time.

Comment: Is there no way to be able to do this in Python? (My apologies, I'm not very fluent in programming, kinda just above beginner level here...)

Comment: I was assuming you would implement it in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a bunch of conditionals to solve this problem.

The code is inelegant, and involves a lot of repetition, but for a quick-and-dirty script that I'll use over and over, I think it suffices.

```
##here, i process all the gibson primers to get the final list of primers##
##=======================================================================##
    construct_num = 1
    temp = []
    part_num = 1
    temp_row_num = 1
    max_seq_num = 0

    for row in gibson_primer_temp_list:

        max_seq_num = 0

        for x in gibson_primer_temp_list:
            if int(x[1]) > construct_num:
                pass
            if int(x[1]) == construct_num:
                max_seq_num += 1
##        print('Const. number counter is at ' + str(construct_num) + ' and current maximum known number of sequences is ' + str(max_seq_num))

##        print(row[1])

##        if int(row[1]) < construct_num:
##            while construct_num < int(row[1]):
##        print(max_seq_num)
##        for row in gibson_primer_temp_list:
##            if int(row[1]) == construct_num:
##                max_seq_num += 1
##            if int(row[1]) > construct_num:
##                break

        #print('Construct number is ' + str(row[1]) + ' and seq. number is ' + str(row[4]))
        #print('Const. number counter is ' + str(construct_num) + ' and max. seq. number is ' + str(max_seq_num) + '.')

        if int(row[1]) > construct_num:
            part_num = 1
            while construct_num < int(row[1]):
                #print('Construct number is ' + str(construct_num))
                construct_num += 1
##                temp_row_num += 1 #do not uncomment
            #continue - not to be added back again!

        if int(row[1]) == construct_num:

            if int(row[4]) == max_seq_num:

                #print(row)
                temp.append(row)
                temp_row_num += 1
                #print('We are going to make primers that join the first and last part in construct ' + str(construct_num))
                #print('Grabbing overhang portion from part ' + str(part_num) + ', which is sequence ' + str(row[4]) + '. It has the sequence ' + str(row[0]))
                overhang = row
                #print('Grabbing the first sequence...')
                for x in gibson_primer_temp_list:
                    #print(row[1] == x[1] and x[4] == 1)
                    if row[1] == x[1] and x[4] == 1:
                        #print(x[0])
                        anneal = x
                        #print('The first sequence is ' + str(anneal))
                        fw_primer = overhang[0] + anneal [0]
                        #print('The forward primer on the first part is: ' + str(fw_primer))
                        primer_list.append([fw_primer, construct_num, x[2], 'fw primer'])
                        break

                #print('Grabbing the third sequence...')
                for y in gibson_primer_temp_list:
                    #print(row[1] == y[1] and y[4] == 3)
                    if row[1] == y[1] and y[4] == 3:
                        #print(y[0])
                        overhang = y
                        #print('The third sequence is ' + str(overhang))
                        break

                #print('Grabbing the (n-2)th sequence...')
                steps_backward = 2
                target_seq_num = max_seq_num - steps_backward
                for z in gibson_primer_temp_list:
                    #print(row[1] == z[1] and z[4] == target_seq_num)
                    if row[1] == z[1] and z[4] == target_seq_num:
                        #print(z[0])
                        anneal = z
                        #print('The n-2th sequence is ' + str(anneal))
                        break

                re_primer = overhang[0] + anneal[0]
                primer_list.append([re_primer, construct_num, z[2], 're primer'])
                continue

            if part_num == int(row[2]) and part_num == 1: #if the part number counter = part number
                #print(row)
                temp.append(row)
                temp_row_num += 1
                continue #do NOT delete this continue

            if part_num < int(row[2]):
                #print('Current part is: ' + str(part_num) + '. Upping part number.' + '\n')
                part_num += 1
                #do NOT add in a "continue" here


            if part_num == int(row[2]) and row[3] == 'fp_anneal':
                #print(row)
                temp.append(row)
                temp_row_num += 1
                #print('Current part is: ' + str(part_num))
                #print('Grabbing tp_overhang from part ' + str(part_num - 1) + '...')
                x = 1
                for row in temp:
                    x += 1
                    if x == temp_row_num - 1:
                        prev_tp_overhang = row
                #print('Sequence of tp_overhang from part ' + str(part_num - 1) + ' is: ' + prev_tp_overhang[0])
                fw_primer_current = prev_tp_overhang[0] + row[0]
                #print('Appending to master primer list...')
                primer_list.append([fw_primer_current, construct_num, part_num, 'fw primer'])
                #print('Forward primer is: ' + str(fw_primer_current) + '\n')
                continue

            if part_num == int(row[2]) and row[3] == 'tp_anneal':
                #print(row)
                temp.append(row)
                temp_row_num += 1
                continue


            if part_num == int(row[2]) and row[3] == 'fp_overhang':
                #print(row)
                temp.append(row)
                temp_row_num += 1
                #print('Current temp_row_num is ' + str(temp_row_num))
                #print('Current part is: ' + str(part_num))
                #print('Grabbing tp_anneal from part ' + str(part_num - 1) + '...')
                x = 1
                for row in temp:
                    x += 1
                    if x == temp_row_num - 5:
                        prev_tp_anneal = row
                        #print(row)
                        pass
                #print('Sequence of tp_anneal from part ' + str(part_num - 1) + ' is: ' + prev_tp_anneal[0])
                re_primer_prev = row[0] + prev_tp_anneal[0]
                #print('Appending to master primer list...')
                primer_list.append([re_primer_prev, construct_num, part_num - 1, 're primer'])
                #print('Reverse primer for previous part is: ' + str(re_primer_prev) + '\n')
                part_num += 1
                continue

            if part_num == int(row[2]) and row[3] == 'tp_overhang':
                #print(row)
                temp.append(row)
                temp_row_num += 1
                continue

            continue
```

Thanks everybody for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Martineau probably has the right idea with a domain-specific language. I don't have any experience with that, but here's what I came up with in a half hour.

I haven't run or debugged or tested this, but if you have any questions, let me know. This code also assumes that the fragment lengths aren't so long as to have problems with holding them in memory. If that assumption doesn't hold true, this approach won't be very efficient.

I was also lazy in my design of the fragments dictionary. It really shouldn't be a global variable, and this entire code should be in a class.

```
def head(seq, count):
    return seq[count:]

def tail(seq, count):
    return seq[:count]

def reverse(nt):
    if nt in 'Gg':
        return 'C'
    elif nt in 'Cc':
        return 'G'
    elif nt in 'Aa':
        return 'T'
    elift nt in 'Tt':
        return 'A'
    raise Exception('invalid nucleotide')

def complement(seq):
    return (reverse(i) for i in seq)

def identity(seq):
    return seq

fragments = {}
def register(fragment, name):
    if name not in fragments:
        fragments[name] = fragment
    else:
        raise Exception('a fragment of that name is already registered!')

def make_combination(portions):
    """ Each entry in portions should be a tuple consisting of:
    (sequence name, count, accessor function, complement function)"""
    output = []
    for entry in portions:
        name, count, select, order = entry
        section = order(select(fragments[name], count))
        output.append(str(section))
    # return a string, not a list
    return ''.join(output)

def example()
    a = 'gattaca'
    b = 'tagacat'
    c = 'gagatac'
    register(a, 'a')
    register(b, 'b')
    register(c, 'c')
    # the last 20 nucleotides (n.t.) of C with the first 40 n.t. of A
    first = (('c', 20, tail, identity),
             ('a', 40, head, identity))
    # RC of the first 20 n.t. of B with the RC of the last n.t. of A,
    second = (('b', 20, head, complement),
              ('a', 1, tail, identity))
```

Comment: That's a great starting point for me, Brenden. Thanks for your help!